# Ubuntu 20.04 - No display modes

Tags: display

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, I want to connect my another monitor but I have no display modes in my settings.

can anyone help with that, please?

[image: screenshot of Settings > Displays]

Comment: Did you change GRUB to start the Linux kernel with nomodeset argument? I did that to fix the Linux kernel failing to load the Nvidia drivers and causing it to not show any UI. But the side effect I noticed later is the system becomes oblivious to changes in displays.

Comment: The display mode options will be available only when you connect a monitor to your system.
If the monitor is not connected it won't show the options.

Comment: I've also had this problem. But all is fine with your Displays Settings. You should just connect to your second screen by HDMI(as i did) or smth else. And just after connection it extended me this menu. I haven't downloaded anything and all works properly. My Ubuntu version 21.10.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I have all 3 monitors connected, but no display mode in the settings.